# Limit of the ratio of two Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to obtain the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{J_0(2\sqrt{(n+1)x)}}{J_0(2\sqrt{nx)}}
$$

where $J_0$ is the Bessel function of the first kind .

I am trying to obtain the following limit:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{L^{(2)}_{n+1}(x)}{L^{(2)}_n(x)}
$$

where $L^{(2)}_p(x)$ is the Laguerre function. I thought in Bessel functions in the limit of large argument $nx$ will be easier as $n\to\infty$

Comment: As $n \to \infty$, $\sqrt{(n+1)x} \to \sqrt{nx}$, so intuitively the limit is $1$. I don't know how to formally show this though.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I'm skeptical of the intuition. I was trying to think then, taking a continuous function $f(\sqrt{(n+1)x})$ and $f(\sqrt{nx})$ are you expecting the limit of the ratio to always be one? $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{f(\sqrt{(n+1)x})}{f(\sqrt{nx})}=1?$ What if $f(x)=e^{x^2}$?

Comment: @snulty Hmm you are right. I think there would have to be some added condition on $f(x)$ for it to work out.

Comment: Numerical experiments suggest that this limit is not always $1$. I'll study this further.

Comment: Apparently the limit does not exist. Let $j_{0, k}$ be the $k$th zero of $J_0$. If $n = j^2_{0, k}/(4 x) + \alpha$ with $|\alpha| \leq 1/2$, the ratio of the Bessel functions is approximately $1 + 1/\alpha$ for large $k$. Values of $k$ which give $j^2_{0, k}/(4 x)$ close to an integer will give large absolute values of the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

FYI,

I have my doubts about integrals in the last step.

Applying one of the integral representations of Bessel function:

$J_k(z)=\frac{2^{1-k}z^k}{\sqrt\pi\Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+k)}\int\limits_0^\pi (1-t^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}+k}\cos(zt)dt\tag1$

In our case $k=0$, $z_1=2\sqrt{(n+1)x}$ and  $z_2=2\sqrt{nx}$ so the limit is the following:

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_0^1 (1-t^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos\big(2t\sqrt{(n+1)x}\big)dt}{\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_0^1 (1-t^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cos\big(2t\sqrt{nx}\big)dt}\tag2$

Performing the following substitutions accordance with the integrals:

$\sqrt{4xr}=2t\sqrt{(n+1)x}$ and  $\sqrt{4xr}=2t\sqrt{nx}$  we get:

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}} \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{n+1} (1-\frac{r^2}{(n+1)^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\cos\big(2\sqrt{(rx}\big)}{\sqrt{r}}dr}{\int\limits_0^{n} (1-\frac{r^2}{n^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\cos\big(2\sqrt{rx}\big)}{\sqrt{r}}dr}\tag3$

Take the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$

$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{n}{n+1}}}_{\rightarrow 1}
 \dfrac{\int\limits_0^{\infty} \overbrace{(1-\frac{r^2}{(n+1)^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}}^{\rightarrow 1}\frac{\cos\big(2\sqrt{(rx}\big)}{\sqrt{r}}dr}{\int\limits_0^{\infty} \underbrace{(1-\frac{r^2}{n^2})^{-\frac{1}{2}}}_{\rightarrow 1}\frac{\cos\big(2\sqrt{rx}\big)}{\sqrt{r}}dr}{\rightarrow 1}\tag4$

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \cos(\sqrt r)/\sqrt r \, dr$ diverges.